# Getting "Timed out receiving message from renderer" while running selenium script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chrome v81 and ChromeDriver vChromeDriver 81.0.4044.20. My selenium script is running successfully and able to identify web elements also. But i am using one loop there, which is not working-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String projectPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", projectPath + "\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/AutomationPractice/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        WebElement cb = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='option1']"));
        cb.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if (cb.isSelected())
            cb.click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);

        List<WebElement> allCBs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@value='checkbox']"));
        for (int i = 0; i < allCBs.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }

        driver.close();
    }
```

**Output-**

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[1588922113.669][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
[1588922113.771][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your xpath with this:

```
//*[@id='checkbox-example']/child::*/descendant::input
```

Comment: This will work and also the reason why the code isn't working is because the attribute is "type" and not "value" Correct one is `//input[@type='checkbox']`

Comment: My mistake it should be type instead of value. It's working now. But the
"[1588922113.669][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 0.100"
still coming so many times.

Comment: Put Explicit  wait before finding elements.